# Strange caching of Palette's TaggingRules

Tags: front-end, notebooks, palettes, inheritance

Please follow those steps to get the idea about the problem:

1. Let's create a palette:

   ```
   nb = CreatePalette[
      DynamicModule[{},
       Panel["Hello you!", ImageSize -> 500, Alignment -> Center]
       ,
       SynchronousInitialization -> False,
       Initialization :> (
         CreateDocument@CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules]
       )
      ],
      WindowTitle -> "Palette B ",
      TaggingRules -> {"B" -> 1123}
   ];
   ```
2. And save it to users palettes directory.

   ```
   palettePath = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
       "FrontEnd", "Palettes", "TESTPalette.nb"}];

   NotebookSave[  nb,   palettePath   ];
   NotebookClose @ nb;
   ```
3. Reset menus to show it there:

   ```
   MathLink`CallFrontEnd[ FrontEnd`ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic, Automatic}]]
   ```

   > [image]
4. Click on the item or run `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenFromPalettesMenu", 
   FileNameTake @ palettePath]` and we have it working:

   > [image]
5. Close the palette and delete it.

   ```
   DeleteFile @ palettePath
   ```
6. Repeat steps 1-4 with different `TaggingRules`

   ```
    WindowTitle -> "Palette A",
    TaggingRules -> {"A" -> 1112}
   ```

#### The problem

**Now there is a new Palette's Menu item - "Palette A" - and that notebook is opened when clicked, yet the old TaggingRules with `"B"` are prompted...**

> [image]

- But the file is saved correctly:

  ```
  FilePrint @ palettePath
  ```

  shows that there is `"A"` inside `TaggingRules`. So `"B"` was somehow, cached somewhere.
- Also, when one opens the notebook manually or with `NotebookOpen @ paletePath` it works well...
- The problem remains after restarting Mathematica.
- The `SynchronousInitialization` option is necessary, I wasn't able to reproduce the problem without it.

What is going on and how to deal with this?

Comment: I think the caching is documented in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StoringAndTrackingPaletteStates.html

Comment: @ilian I think that's it, been there forgot that. Yet I'm surprised that there is a difference in using Preemprive or Main link. Do you want to answer? should I answer the support about finding the issue? Moreover, I don't like all those exceptions that are trying to make my life easier, it's usually the oposite :)

Comment: Support has been made aware of that tutorial. It was actually new to me so I'd leave writing the answer to the more knowledgeable about the FE (perhaps you should self-answer!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian), this behaviour is explained in [**StoringAndTrackingPaletteStates tutorial**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StoringAndTrackingPaletteStates.html).

Shortly, `` CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, System`PalettesMenuSettings] `` keeps those values cached.

In order to achieve what I described in the question we have to drop an entry that coresponds to our palette.

It doesn't really matter when it's done. Just do it before you need it to work :)

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, System`PalettesMenuSettings] = DeleteCases[
  CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, System`PalettesMenuSettings],
  FileNameTake[palettePath] -> _
]
```