# Factor fails on a simple expression

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions, factorization

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 11.3.0**

---

Consider the following symbolic expression (all the `c`'s are undefined)

```
exp = (-4*I)*(-1 + c22)*Pi*c1[c7[c12], c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]]*
c13[{c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]}, c10[c25], c10[c24]]*
c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[l, c6]]*
c4[c5[p2, c6], c6].c4[c5[l, c6], c6].c4[c5[p1, c6], c6]*c40[c15]*
c40[c20] - (4*I)*(-1 + c22)*Pi*
c1[c7[c12], c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]]*
c13[{c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]}, c10[c25], c10[c24]]*
c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p2, c6]]*
c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c5[p2, c6], c6]*c40[c14]*c40[c15]*
c40[c20] - (4*I)*(-1 + c22)*Pi*
c1[c7[c12], c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]]*
c13[{c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]}, c10[c25], 
 c10[c24]]*(c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p1, c6]] - 
  2*c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p2, c6]] + 
  c8[c5[p2, c6], 
   c5[p2, c6]])*(c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[
    c11[c15, c6], c6] - 
  c4[c5[p2, c6], c6].c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] + 
  c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c11[c15, c6], c6]*c40[c14] - 
  c4[c5[p2, c6], c6].c4[c11[c15, c6], c6]*c40[c14])*c40[c15]*
c40[c20] + (4*I)*(-1 + c22)*Pi*
c1[c7[c12], c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]]*
c13[{c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]}, c10[c25], c10[c24]]*
c8[c11[c15, c6], 
 c5[p1, c6]]*(c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c5[p1, c6],
     c6] - c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c5[p2, c6], 
    c6] - c4[c5[p2, c6], c6].c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c5[p1, c6], 
    c6] + c4[c5[p2, c6], c6].c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c5[p2, c6], 
    c6] + c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c5[p1, c6], c6]*c40[c14] - 
  c4[c5[p1, c6], c6].c4[c5[p2, c6], c6]*c40[c14] - 
  c4[c5[p2, c6], c6].c4[c5[p1, c6], c6]*c40[c14] + 
  c4[c5[p2, c6], c6].c4[c5[p2, c6], c6]*c40[c14])*c40[c15]*
c40[c20];
```

Now try to evaluate the following code

```
AbsoluteTiming[res1 = Simplify[exp];]
AbsoluteTiming[res2 = Factor[exp];]
Simplify[res1 - res2]
```

On Mathematica 8 (Linux version) both `Simplify` and `Factor` finish in less than 0.1 seconds. However, with all newer versions (9, 10.3, 11.0) that I have, `Factor` never finishes, while `Simplify` is still very fast.

To me this looks like a bug/regression, but may be someone has a sensible explanation for this behavior. I have not reported this to WRI so far, but I'm planning to do so.

Edit:

`res1` is

```
(-4*I)*(-1 + c22)*Pi*c1[c7[c12], c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]]*
 c13[{c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]}, c10[c25], c10[c24]]*c40[c15]*c40[c20]*
 (c40[c14]*c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p2, c6]]*c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] + c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[l, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[l, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] + 
  (c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p1, c6]] - 2*c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p2, c6]] + 
    c8[c5[p2, c6], c5[p2, c6]])*
   (c40[c14]*(c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] - 
      c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c11[c15, c6], c6]) + 
    c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] - 
    c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c11[c15, c6], c6]) - 
  c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*
   (c40[c14]*(c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] - 
      c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] - c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . 
       c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] + c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p2, c6], c6]) + 
    c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] - 
    c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] - 
    c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] + 
    c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p2, c6], c6]))
```

`res2` is

```
(-4*I)*(-1 + c22)*Pi*c1[c7[c12], c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]]*
 c13[{c7[Glu5], c7[c9[c1312][0]]}, c10[c25], c10[c24]]*c40[c15]*c40[c20]*
 (c40[c14]*c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] - 2*c40[c14]*c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p2, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] + 
  c40[c14]*c8[c5[p2, c6], c5[p2, c6]]*c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] - c40[c14]*c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] + 
  c40[c14]*c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] + c40[c14]*c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p2, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] - 
  c40[c14]*c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] + 2*c40[c14]*c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p2, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] - 
  c40[c14]*c8[c5[p2, c6], c5[p2, c6]]*c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] + c40[c14]*c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] - 
  c40[c14]*c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] + c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] - 
  2*c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p2, c6]]*c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] + c8[c5[p2, c6], c5[p2, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] - 
  c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] + c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] + 
  c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[l, c6]]*c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[l, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] - c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] + 
  2*c8[c5[p1, c6], c5[p2, c6]]*c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] - c8[c5[p2, c6], c5[p2, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c11[c15, c6], c6] + 
  c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . 
    c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] - c8[c11[c15, c6], c5[p1, c6]]*
   c4[c5[p2, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p1, c6], c6] . c4[c5[p2, c6], c6])
```

Comment: "Simple" expression?  Really?  And how could anyone know how "simple" it is when SUNF, SMP, SUNIndes, SUNTF, GaugeXi, LorentzIndex, Momentup, Glu2, and many other terms are not defined?

Comment: In this example all the occurring symbols are undefined. I modified the example to have them just a `c` a number in the name. However, here it really does not matter what `exp` means.  The point is that this example works perfectly with Mahtematica 8 but not any higher version. I regularly use `Factor` and `Simplify` on much more complicated symbolic expressions without any problems. For my standards the given expressions is very simple and it is strange that `Factor` cannot handle it (although it could in MMA 8).

Comment: Could you show the `res1` and `res2` you found in version 8?  How could *Mathematica* simplify terms such as `c7[c9[c1312][0]]` *in principle*?

Comment: I'll look into this. I think I know what might have happened (change of an underlying method switchover).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks. I usually prefer `Factor` over `Simplify` for performance reasons, so this example got me really surprised.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sure. As I said, I use Mathematica for quantum field theory calculations (often with lots of undefined symbols) on a daily basis, and it does its job pretty well.  This particular expression stems from a renormalization calculation in Quantum Chromodynamics. Also, I don't see why Mathematica should have any issues with something like `c7[c9[c1312][0]]`. It is a symbolic expression that can be treated in the same way as `x` or `y` (with some limitations).

Comment: `Factor` should do better here. This will be treated as a bug.

Comment: It would be nice if this could be fixed in 11.2.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau By the way, is there already a case number for this issue? Looks like people for some reason do not like this question (already 3 votes to close it). So if that happens I'd like to have something in a hand to be able to follow the issue with `Factor`. (Sometimes it takes several releases, before a bug is fixed ;) )

Comment: I am not aware of any case number. Is that something one would receive by contacting Technical Services?

Comment: Yes, when one reports a bug to the WRI support and they recognize it as such, they give you a case number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug in [`Factor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html) has been addressed as of version 11.3.0.

While the example may take some seconds to run, it will not hang

```
AbsoluteTiming[res1 = Simplify[exp];]
AbsoluteTiming[res2 = Factor[exp];]
Simplify[res1 - res2]

(* {0.060817, Null} *)
(* {13.5211, Null} *)
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Great, many thanks! I guess there is no simple way to make `Factor` as fast as in version 8 where it also required much less then a second on this expression?

Comment: I have just tried the same example in Mathematica 12.0 on Linux (Fedora 28) and there `Factor` requires 104 seconds (sic!), while `Simplify` finishes in less than 0.0002 seconds. Although `Factor` finishes correctly, the amount of time it spends on this expression as compared to v. 11.3 seems to be way too high. Can this be regarded as a bug?

Comment: @vsht I think an order of magnitude slowdown is definitely worth reporting. It may well be a bug (though it could also be a side effect of fixing a different bug).

Comment: Ok, I've just reported this regression to the WRI support. Let us see what they will reply.

Comment: The performance regression of Factor has been given [CASE:4251515]. Let us hope that it will become fast again in Mathematica 12.1 or so.

Answer (score 3):

```
AbsoluteTiming[res2 = exp // FactorTerms // Factor]
```

gives 0.03 seconds for me using Mathematica 12.0.

Comment: Thanks, Rolf. I am looking into the slowdown, but this aspect caught me by surprise.

Comment: You are welcome. Vlad thought he could get rid of my old Factor2 function from FeynCalc, where several heuristic workarounds for old-time deficencies of Factor are collected, but not quite yet.

Comment: Weirdly enough, there may be examples where the reverse is true: multiplying through by a complex-valued constant could make the factorization faster. (I do not have such an example offhand, but the possibility is there.)

Comment: Rolf is as always superb in finding workarounds when standard functions don't behave as one would like them to. +1 from me. However, the statement is not quite true. I never intended to get rid of [Factor2](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/blob/master/FeynCalc/Shared/Factor.m). In most cases it returns "nicer" results than `Factor`, so it will definitely remain part of FeynCalc. What I wanted to get rid of at some point is [Apart1](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/blob/f1639276d4bf0568b227c52ca95e1604fb487934/FeynCalc/LoopIntegrals/Apart.m#L51), but this is also currently not feasible.

Comment: The reason is that `Apart` still has some performance problems when the expressions contain complex numbers, cf. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112069/performance-of-apart-with-complex-numbers/149466#149466

Comment: I do not understand why Apart or Factor has to be slower when complex numbers are there explicitly. But I am no mathematician and maybe more knowledgable developers like Dan can elucidate. If it is indeed an acknowledged bug by WRI I guess that on a public bug tracker (as suggested [here](https://halirutan.de/discussion/Issue-Tracker-WRI/)) these slow-down bugs would get a lot of votes by frustrated physicists who are forced to use Maple and FORM these days but would like to return to WL.