# How to save palette positions?

Tags: front-end, customization, palettes

I have searched for an answer to this particular *Mathematica* annoyance, but I could not find an answer anywhere:

#### Question

I would really like to be able to save the position and state of my palettes on the screen.

#### Details

I will notice in passing that the question of why this is not their default behavior may better be left unasked. Anyhow...

Specifically, I do like the `WritingAssistant` and a certain configuration of the `BasicMathAssistant`. Alas, those two insist on both occupying the rightmost edge of the screen, and thus appear on top of each other. Having to rearrange them every single time I open *Mathematica* gets old quick.

#### What I've tried

I have tried fiddling with the Notebook files for these and some other palettes in the *Mathematica* installation folder, setting them to be editable and auto-save on exit, install them locally under a different name, and various permutations of these, with limited to no success at all. Interestingly, I could get some of the palettes to behave more or less (in particular I managed to locally install the crucially important `Notation` palette, which isn't even accessible by default under *Mathematica* 11 anymore, and have it appear where I want it), but the others insist on doing whatever it is the are coded to do, including appearing on top of other palettes. I was able to install a private and renamed copy of the `BasicMathAssistant` in my local folder, and I swear it appeared in the Palette menu once, but then it disappeared from the menu, even though the local Notebook file encoding the palette was still there.

Long story short, I clearly don't know how to get these palettes to act in a reasonable way. Does anyone know how to get this to work? I have seen [Community:
Saving palette positions in Windows.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/418943?sortMsg=Flat), but the strategy proposed there does not work for the `BasicMathAssistant`. It does seem to work for the `Notation` palette, albeit only after some massaging, by changing the palette's options so it's editable and auto-saves on exit.

Comment: related: [Strange caching of Palette's TaggingRules](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112061/5478)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using approach from [How to customize the package editor interface?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81016/5478)

```
CopyFile @@ ( FileNameJoin[
  {#, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "Palettes", "BasicMathAssistant.nb"}
] & /@ {$InstallationDirectory, $UserBaseDirectory})

SetOptions[
    NotebookOpen@%, 
    { Saveable -> True, 
      ClosingAutoSave -> True (*thx to Mr. Wizard*)
    }
]
```

When you move/resize/open another tab, the palette state will be saved.

Comment: Changing the last line to `SetOptions[NotebookOpen@%, {Saveable -> True, ClosingAutoSave -> True}]` appears to be a complete solution.  The palettes already appear to be editable, and this eliminates the save confirmation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I forgot about that, I just checked `NotebookAutoSave`.

Comment: Wonderful, this worked. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Kuba for this nice solution.  Got tired of having to move the MMA palettes every dang time it loads.

Comment: Also thanks to @Mr. Wizard for same.